# How to indicate "accessed" attribute in Bibtex file when citing urls with IEEE?

Tags: url, latex, bibtex, citations, ieee

According to the [IEEE](http://wwwlib.murdoch.edu.au/find/citation/ieee.html) citation style reference, in case we cite urls the access time of the url should be indicated as well.

Does anybody know how to indicate this when using BibTeX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the ieeetran bibtex style at the [link](http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/). While there is no 'access time' field, there is a 'note' field for many of the document types which may suit your purpose.

Comment: Thank you. By using note="[Accessed Dec. 2, 2004]", it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the modified bib styles on [urlbst](http://purl.org/nxg/dist/urlbst). This is what I usually use, although I enter the `lastchecked` field manually in my `.bib` file.